# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. Flutter

Tags: android, debugging, flutter

I am trying to debug my Flutter application on Pixel 1 and getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'
```

I've read up on it and have implemented the suggested changes such as adding:

`multiDexEnabled true` to `defaultConfig`.

Any thoughts on how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by downgrading cloud_firestore dependency in pubspec.yaml to ^0.7.0